# EmberJS: preloading data for different parts of the page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to `EmberJS` so far been experimenting and playing with samples.
As it is shown on the mockup I want to load `venues` from server to populate them into a select widget.

What do you recommend to do?

[image]

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. You might want to read through the [Ember.js guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/) and come back with something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A select.  I mean, if you want to preload, inject it into the page, and return it from the model hook.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dijutedo/1/edit